# Arithmetic: different object length

Tags: r

```
a <- 3:10
b <- 1:99
c <- sum(b / a)
Warning message:
In b/a : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
c
[1] 892.8333
```

Hi, I just started playing R recently.
I expect the above to yield 8 values, but it doesn't:

```
(1/3 + 2/3 + … + 99/3) =
(1/4 + 2/4 + … + 99/4) =
…
(1/9 + 2/9 + … + 99/9) =
(1/10 + 2/10 + … + 99/10) =
```

Any suggestion? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can replicate each of the elements in 'a' as the `length` of 'b', divided by 'b', convert to `matrix` and get the column sums (`colSums`)

```
 colSums(matrix(b/rep(a, each=length(b)), ncol=8))
 #[1] 1650.0000 1237.5000  990.0000  825.0000  707.1429  618.7500  550.0000
 #[8]  495.0000
```

---

Or we loop through each element of 'a', divide by 'b', and get the `sum`.

```
sapply(a, function(x) sum(b/x))
#[1] 1650.0000 1237.5000  990.0000  825.0000  707.1429  618.7500  550.0000
#[8]  495.0000
```

---

Or a concise option would  be

```
colSums(outer(b,a, FUN='/'))
```